# magento 2: display cms static page content in phtml file

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages

I have a static cms page. I want to display that page content in my phtml file. Is there way to do this by using that page identifier?

I did something like that for cms blocks.

```
echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('my_block')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 5):

Add following code in your Block class, here Form class is an example

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;


class Form extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
     */
    protected $_filterProvider;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page
     */
    protected $_page;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * Page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_pageFactory;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Page instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Cms\Model\Page
     */
    public function getPage($identifier)
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('page')) {
            /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page */
            $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
            $page->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())->load($identifier, 'identifier');
            $this->setData('page', $page);
        }
        return $this->getData('page');
    }

    public function getContent($identifier)
    {
        return $this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($this->getPage($identifier)->getContent());
    }
}
```

Now you need to just following code for display cms page inside your corresponding phtml file

```
<?php echo $block->getContent('privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode');?>
```

Comment: How can you achieve this if the phtml is shared around pages, and to only content for the page you are viewing?

Answer (score 2):

You have one block related to this template

```
protected $pageFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
){
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
}

public function getCmsPageContent($identifier)
{
    if ($identifier) {
        $content = $this->pageFactory->create();
        $content->load($identifier, 'identifier');
    }
    return $content->getContent();
}
```

You can use this block function in template using below code:

```
echo $block->getCmsPageContent('my_block');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to display cms static page content in any phtml file.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory')->create();
$content->load('page-identifier', 'identifier');
echo $content->getContent();
```

Note : if we use "\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory" so compulsory create it Like $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory')->create(); other wise use following code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
$content->load('page-identifier', 'identifier');
echo $content->getContent();
```

Comment: It's best practice not to use an ObjectManager instance in your code

Answer (score 0):

**This is the correct code for display page content in phtml file.**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
           $content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory')->create();
           $content->load('page-identifier', 'identifier');
           echo $content->getContent();
```